# Change size of SVG clipping mask on mouseover

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to show images using a mask. I tried the css clip-path but because the browser support is that poor I want to use an svg for clipping. My question is how can i change the size of the mask on mousover?

Like here:
[image]

I am using this code at the moment:

```html
 <svg>
  <defs>
     <!--defines the shape to use for clipping-->
     <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
   </defs>
   <clipPath id="clip">
     <!--creates the clipping mask from the shape-->
     <use xlink:href="#circle" overflow="visible"></use>
   </clipPath>
   <!--group containing the image with clipping applied-->
   <g clip-path="url(#clip)">
     <image overflow="visible" xlink:href="model_detail.jpg"></image>
   </g>
</svg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, since you need to resize both the circle and the clipped image, you may scale the svg element on hover like so:

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
svg:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
 <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200">
  <defs>
     <!--defines the shape to use for clipping-->
     <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
   </defs>
   <clipPath id="clip">
     <!--creates the clipping mask from the shape-->
     <use xlink:href="#circle" overflow="visible"></use>
   </clipPath>
   <!--group containing the image with clipping applied-->
   <g clip-path="url(#clip)">
     <image overflow="visible" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg"></image>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Please observe that I've added a `viewBox` and a `width` attribute to the svg. If you don't declare the `viewBox` and the `width` the svg element will have a size of 300px/150px and the part of the circle that falls outside the svg canvas will be cuted off.

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting

> I don't want to scale the image, just the mask. Is that possible?

This is how I would do it: In the next example I'm using transitions to scale the circle when you mouse over the svg element:

```
#c{transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;}

svg:hover #c {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Next comes a working example:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
}

#c{transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;}

svg:hover #c {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-150 -150 300 300" width="200">
  <defs>

   
   <clipPath id="clip">
     <!--creates the clipping mask from the shape-->
     <circle id="c" r="100" />
   </clipPath>
     </defs>
   <!--group containing the image with clipping applied-->
    
     <image clip-path="url(#clip)" id="img" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" x="-150" y="-150" width="300" height="300"></image> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't want to scale the image, just the mask. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it easily with JavaScript, adding an eventlistener onMouseOver over a class.
However, if you need CSS, you can an animation that will do it,like this.

```
 .zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
}
</style>

<div class="zoom"></div>
```